# Sending a JSON formatted string through HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, json, rest, httpurlconnection

I've done some research on using HttpUrlConnect and most examples I've seen uses either 
a) a params string which looks like this:

```
paramString = "param1=someParam&param2=2ndparam&param3=3rdparam";
```

b) uses a put method to place the parameters:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("param1", "Parameter");
json.put("param2", "Parameter2");
json.put("param3", "Parameter3");
```

The format I want to send looks like this:

```
{
    "grant_type":"password",
    "username":"testuser@someid.com",
    "password":"testPwd123$"
}
```

Is there a way for me to send a formatted JSON string instead of setting parameters or using a param string? The code I'm using to send my POST request looks like the following:

```
public static String PostRequest(String urlString, String token, String jsonString) throws IOException {
    byte[] postData = jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.write(postData);
    }

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST response code: " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

I'm open to suggestions whether to use a different library, or if there are any code changes that I should make in order to take a JSON formatted string.

Comment: Your PostRequest method looks good... but the question is what is on the server side?

Comment: If you're posting JSON content, then you need to set the Content-Type to `application/json`.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks, that solved it.  And I promptly find that some of the calls are configured to take application/json.  I wish you made it an actual response so I can set that as the answer I'm looking for.